# Image not moving in the browser window

Tags: html, position, z-index

I have an image which I would like to position near the right margin of my HTML page, and hover over all else on the page. I would also like the image to stay near the right margin when the window is resized. As of now, the image stays in a fixed position within the browser window instead, even appearing outside the page content area when the browser window is extended wide. My page content is centered in the browser window. Below is the code on the image:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="top">
<table width="900" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
<tr>
<td background="../images/FWA_INV_head.jpg" valign="top" align="center">
<img src="images/bannerX.png" border="0" class="image" style="position:absolute;z-index:90;>
```

and here is the CSS:

```
.image {    
position:absolute;
opacity:.90;
-moz-opacity:.90;
filter:alpha(opacity=90);
}
```

Please help me see the error of my ways.

Answer (score 0):

When positioning an absolute element your absolute position is positioned inside of the nearest relative position.  So it's absolutely positioned inside the relative position.  Also your inline style has no closing "

Comment: "When positioning an absolute element your absolute position is positioned inside of the nearest relative position." Actually it's positioned with respect to the closest _positioned_ ancestor. Not just the relatively positioned ones.

Comment: oh I'm not sure I knew that.  Whenever I position something absolute, I usually make sure it's inside a relative positioned container so it won't get skewed results no matter how the DOM tree changes (assuming it's parent container is always there).